# Hide/Remove Ribbon from AllItems.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, customization

I need hide or remove this ribbon menu (new, edit, flow) from this view.
Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user only has Read permissions on this list, he can only view the following options on the ribbon in Modern experience for the list.

[image]

To hide this whole ribbon, we may need scripts such as JavaScript or CSS. But you are using the **Modern** experience. Modern experience does not support Script Editor web part. The [web parts on the Modern page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-web-parts-on-SharePoint-Online-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0) are different with web parts on Classic page.

Currently, the following customizations are unsupported in Modern lists:

•   Custom master pages - More extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options

•   User custom actions / Custom JavaScript - There will be a more controlled way to embed JavaScript on the pages through the SharePoint Framework Extensions (currently in dev preview)

•   Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property

•   JSLink-based view customizations

Learn more about [customizing the “modern” experiences in SharePoint Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice you should create a page and insert your view web part and remove the toolbar.

then Remove the navigation from the header.

And finally remove the ribbon from the page with an script editor to hide the ribbon with css

`#s4-ribbonrow{display:none}`

i would also try to find the reason why the ribbon should be removed instead of removing the permissions.